# When adding a repository can I add an auto enter command in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, package-management, ppa, repository

When I add a repository I would like to add a command so that I do not have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on my keyboard. Just like when you add `-y` to a command when installing a program.

Is that possible?

Comment: The manual page for add-apt-repository says `-y, --yes Assume yes to all queries`. Is it not working on your system?

Comment: @steeldriver seems a perfect answer to me ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. The command is of the form:

```
sudo  apt-add-repository -y repository
```

where `repository` is the name of the repository you wish to add. The `-y` switch performs the same function as in `apt-get`, assuming "yes" to all queries.

Sources:

- [@steeldriver's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784889/when-adding-a-repository-can-i-add-an-auto-enter-command-in-the-terminal#comment1176909_784889): [`man apt-add-repository`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `echo` command along with a pipe to simulate pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and automate the process, like this:

```
echo | sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vbernat/haproxy-2.8
```

This will send an empty line to the `add-apt-repository` command, effectively simulating pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and allowing the script to continue without user interaction.

**Note**: the use of sudo may prompt for your password, and you should ensure that the script is run with the necessary privileges.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`yes`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/yes.1.html) command as follows:

```
yes | sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vbernat/haproxy-2.8
```

What `yes` does is output a string continuously until killed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. So if you run:

```
yes
```

you get:

```
y
y
y
y
y
y
...
```

`yes` also accepts custom strings that are then continuously repeated. For example, if you run:

```
yes no
```

you get:

```
no
no
no
no
no
no
...
```

The benefit of the `yes` command is that you can automatically accept a prompt that asks for a `[y/n]` input (or whatever the input may be for the prompt) even if it does not offer a `-y` flag.

Comment: That's a nice one +1