# The "-y" flag in apt-get command

Tags: configuration, automation, haproxy

Running `apt-get` with the `-y` flag helps runninng the command without waiting for user input. This is good when trying to run an automated script.

However `add-apt-repository ppa:vbernat/haproxy-2.8` requires user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than the usual `(yes/no/fingerprint)`

Does the `-y` also help to skip user input in `add-apt-repository ppa:vbernat/haproxy-2.8`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `echo` command along with a pipe to simulate pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and automate the process, like this:

```
echo | sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vbernat/haproxy-2.8
```

This will send an empty line to the `add-apt-repository` command, effectively simulating pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and allowing the script to continue without user interaction.

**Note**: the use of sudo may prompt for your password, and you should ensure that the script is run with the necessary privileges.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote??

Comment: According to [`man apt-add-repository`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html), the `-y` option exists in `apt-add-repository`, so that's why you got the first downvote I suppose. I have also downvoted your post for this reason, but I'm more than happy to remove the downvote if you remove the first part of your answer. Even better, you could remove your answer from here and post it in [When adding a repository can I add an auto enter command in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/784889/618353). I will also upvote it if you do so! Thank you! :)

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog, I have edited the question. Kindly review.

Comment: Thanks! I removed my downvote and upvoted your answer in [When adding a repository can I add an auto enter command in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/784889/618353)